# Is there any way to go straight to the bottom of the tower?

Tags: tiny-tower

I have noticed that tapping the icon for the number of floors in the top right hand corner takes you straight to the top of the tower, but I can't find any way to go to the bottom.  Has anyone found a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

To go directly to the top of your tower, tap the very top of your screen ( above the zoom button or on the floor count icon)

You can go directly to the bottom of your tower - to my knowledge- only by the notification short cut, such as: restock on a lower floor, VIP, or someone in the elevator.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version (march 2017) you can go to the bottom by tapping on the status bar (where your balance is shown).

Going to the top remained the same - tap on upper screen border.